# NetSparkle : managing data files

Tags: .net, installation, upgrade

I have a .Net application which I want to have automatic update feature with NetSparkle.

Every time I create an update of my application, I want that new update uses already stored data in the pre-existing installation directory on user's computer.

For example here is structure of my application files

```
app.exe
some.dll
database.db
```

When user uses the app the database builds up and contains information necessary for application functioning.

When I publish a new update a new database.db is used which is empty..

How can I make previous database file available with new updated exe/dlls instead of empty database file ?

PS: may be its a very basic thing in , but I am absolutely new to NetSparkle.

Please help thank you..